# Entropy relations in classical-quantum states with conditioned independence

Tags: linear-algebra, min-entropy

Consider a classical-quantum (pure) state $\rho_{AEBC}$ where $A,C$ are classical registers.
Suppose $\rho$ can be written in the following form:
$$\rho = \sum_{c} \alpha_c \vert  c\rangle\langle c|\otimes \rho^c_{AE} \otimes \rho^c_{B}$$.

That is conditioned on $C=c$, register $B$ is in tensor with $AE$.
I am trying to show that,
$H_{\infty}(A \vert EBC)= H_{\infty}(A|EC)$.
One side follows directly by data processing inequality. So, we need to show $H_{\infty}(A \vert EBC) \geq H_{\infty}(A|EC)$. I know that if $\rho_{XYZ}= \rho_{XY} \otimes \rho_{Z}$, then $H_{\infty}(X\vert YZ)=  H_{\infty}(X \vert Y)$.

Comment: as currently written that doesn't really make sense. Maybe you meant to write something like $|c\rangle\!\langle c|\otimes \rho^c_{AE}\otimes\rho_B^c$?